# Is it possible to programmatically get the speech synthesizer manufacturer's identity?

Tags: basic4android

My application needs to know the speech synthesizer manufacturer's identity. The "Default Engine" which is set in Android's TTS settings. Knowing this piece of information would allow me to custom tailor my app to take advantage of individual synthesizer capabilities.

Hope there's a way

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer...

```
Dim P as Phone : msgbox(P.GetSettings("tts_default_synth"),"")
```